# Service console/Omni-channel: Unable to log you in to this app using presence status

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnichannel

We have enabled the service console and Omni-channel in a sandbox and configured several statusses (Online, Offline, On a break). On the first day, everything went smoothly. Everyone saw the available statusses and could use them.

The next day: all users get the error "Unable to log you in to this app using presence status. To not lose work, return to the previous app." The only available status is Offline.

Googling the message does not help. "Return to the previous app" is not exactly helpful. How can we reset everyone so that we can get Online again in Omni-channel?

Update: it's 5 days later, Monday morning, and: no error message and all presence statusses are available.

Comment: We've been getting a very similar error since Spring '24 entered our sandboxes. Users are still able to access omni-channel and statuses, they just need to refresh, however, it's a persistent error we see on every login.

Answer (score 0):

This has been raised as a Known issue or BUG by the Product team>>
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000yGCUJAA4/we-had-an-unexpected-error-try-again-or-contact-your-salesforce-admin-for-help-on-service-console

Comment: This does not look like the same issue to me.